# Sequelize error when using $notIn to prevent string based operators

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm in Sequelize 5.21.8 version, trying use a no string based operators that are now deprecated.
But I'm getting this:

It's working fine (with string based):
where: {id_ativo:  { [Op.notIn] : arr }

It's NOT working:
where: {id_ativo:  { $notIn : arr }

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Error: Invalid value { '$notIn': [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ] }

Comment: Did you try `{id_ativo: { '$notIn' : arr } ` ?

Comment: I have already set operatorsAliases like this:

const Op = sequelize.Op;
const operatorsAliases = { 
  $eq: Op.eq,
  $ne: Op.ne,...

Then this is working, but with this a alert:
(node:17724) [SEQUELIZE0003] DeprecationWarning: String based operators are deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators

Comment: Then try `{id_ativo: { [$notIn] : arr } `

Comment: `$notIn` is the string based and you are doing good on having `[Op.notIn]`. Try removing `operatorsAliases` from config and use `[Op.notIn]`. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8417#issuecomment-334056048